# How can I create a rpm that includes rpm modules with maven?

Tags: mapping, rpm-maven-plugin, requires

I am trying to generate a "rpm container" with rpm-maven-plugin. This container should include three rpm I have generated before and shared in a yum repository. So the idea is to have an empty project with a pom file that generates a rpm file, which contains just three rpms that come from the repository. My problem is that I do not want to include anything else, so I do not need to map anything in there because the rpms inside they have their own mapping configuration and postinstall scripts. I add a small example to explain my question better.

- I have in a local yum repository (aaa.repo) three projects proj1.rpm, proj2.rpm, proj3.rpm.
- I have created a new project with a lonely pom.xml with rpm-plugin to make a "global" rpm which contains these three projects, what I have done so far is this:

< plugin>

```
< groupId>org.codehaus.mojo< /groupId>
<artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1-alpha-2</version>
<inherited>false</inherited>
<executions>
...
</executions>
<configuration>
    ...
<provides>
<provide>dump</provide>
</provides>
<requires>
<require>proj1</require>
<require>proj2</require>
<require>proj3</require>
</requires>
<mappings>
<mapping>
<directory>/usr/local/globalProject</directory>    
</mapping>
</mappings>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

I had to add an empty mapping because it does not run without it.
When I execute:

sudo yum -v --nogpgcheck localinstall globalProject.noarch.rpm

It resolves the dependencies but it does not install the content of the rpms.
Any ideas?